# get value from prepared statement query android?

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

i have a doubt that how to get the result of the prepared statement query in android.Actually i have a need that i want the row id from database while comparing a field words which can contain ' or" so i want to use prepared statement ,after googling out i did not get any proper example for android sqlite database ,please tell me how to use the prepared statement in android and after running query ,how to use value either through result set or through cursor.below is query look like-

```
String perfect_stmnt="select ID from Annotation where   HighlightedWord=? ";

        try{
            ** Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("file:/"+ db.getPath());**
            pstmt = con.prepareStatement(perfect_stmnt);


            pstmt.setString(1, highlightword);


            Resultset rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
```

Here the major doubt i am having how to get the connection here see the line having **

Thanks

Comment: DriverManager ???, you are too far, Please refer http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: @VenomVendor but there is no proper example of prepared statement whose query will return data to either cursor/resultset

Comment: daniel, what's happens? do you need to work like a programmer? oh my god. cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android database API can prepare a statement (see [compileStatement](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#compileStatement%28java.lang.String%29)), but it is not possible to get a cursor or result set from that.
You can use compiled statements only if they return a single value, or nothing.

Please note that SQLite does not have a large overhead when preparing statements, so you can just call `query` or `rawQuery` multiple times.

Comment: gd but in my case always return value will be a single numeric value can i get that??

Comment: Then call [simpleQueryForLong](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteStatement.html#simpleQueryForLong%28%29).

Comment: Will it be the result of query or what?

Comment: "**Returns** The result of the query."

Comment: Thanks for your effort and i am check it so if work surely i'll accept it